# SDK GridRefresh Call Throwing Exception

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm going to try to explain this as best I can, please feel free to ask for clarifications as required.

Using IE10, CRM Online with RU12.

I am playing about with subgrids and getting them to refresh. Consider the following script, which I have nicked wholesale from MSDN (and wrapped in a try/catch block)

```
function start() {
    try {
        var controls = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(isSubGrid);

        if (controls.length > 0) {

            var subGridNames = "";
            for (var i in controls) {
                controls[i].refresh();
                subGridNames += (" - " + controls[i].getName() + "\n");
            }
            alert("The following subgrids were refreshed: \n" + subGridNames);
        }
        else {
            alert("There are no subgrid controls on the current form.");
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
}

function isSubGrid (control)
{
    return control.getControlType() == "subgrid";
}
```

Nothing special going on there - get all controls of type `subgrid` (this returns 10 elements as expected) and call `refresh()` on them.

However this is consistently failing on the first call to `refresh()`.

The exception details is fairly straightforward

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'Refresh' of undefined or null reference
```

Which suggests that the `control[i]` is null when called in the loop at this point here

```
for (var i in controls) {
    controls[i].refresh();//error thrown here - suggests controls[i] is null
    subGridNames += (" - " + controls[i].getName() + "\n");
}
```

However I can see that it isn't null (and has the method `refresh` as expected).

[image]

I can make it work by using `setInterval`

```
function waitAndThenRefresh(gridname) {
    var grid = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(gridname);
    var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        if (grid === null || grid._control === null || grid._control._element === null) {
            return;
        }
        if (grid._control._element.readyState === 'complete') {
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
            if (grid != null) {
                grid.refresh();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

But that is pretty hideous, not to mention does not explain with the SDK call doesn't work as expected.

So I guess the question is: has anyone else seen this issue? Or can you replicate it on another instance? Am I missing something? There is nothing in the SDK that suggests you need to defer calling `refresh` until the inner control's `readyState` is `complete`?

Answer (score 1):

The code block you are using,

```
for (var i in controls) {
    controls[i].refresh();
    subGridNames += (" - " + controls[i].getName() + "\n");
}
```

should be replaced with the following:

```
for (var i in controls) {
    i.refresh();
    subGridNames += (" - " + i.getName() + "\n");
}
```

or:

```
for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
    controls[i].refresh();
    subGridNames += (" - " + controls[i].getName() + "\n");
}
```

You are getting the exception because `controls[i]` is undefined in your case, `i` being the control (the element of the array `controls`).

Comment: Apologies for delayed response. Whilst I can absolutely see what you are saying, it produces the same error. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a CRM-buddy of mine. He said that the issue depends on the new refreshment Engine. According to him, it's sort of a bug but not really. If I got it right, the refresh has been reengineered to accommodate the new perpetual saving functionality.